# local database fails to start after installing polymer through bower in meteor

Tags: meteor, polymer, bower

I was trying to install bower into meteor and after I did that i tried to instal Polymer through bower .I run the meteor command on my project to start the local database and it presents me a massive error :

> Public/components/polymer/test/unit/dynamic-imports/dynamic-element.html:1:
>   Can't set DOCTYPE here. (Meteor sets  for you)
>   Public/components/polymer/src/lib/template/x-repeat.html:87: bad
>   formatting in HTML template

This error appears like 50 times the only thing that is changing is the html file.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't know bower or polymer, but it seems that you have added html files to your project folder that, well, set the doctype, which I guess meteor doesn't like. Keep in mind that *all* html file anywhere in your project folder (other than `public` (lower case)), will be interpreted and compiled by meteor. So that might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use public instead of Public to store polymer elements files.

Comment: nah it did not work but thanks for the tip ... ! i think there is an issue in my installation will try to reinstall it  and see what happens